# A reversible hash function for storage

Tags: solidity

Does solidity have a reversible hash function. I'm trying to turn an array of uint256s into a hash for storage purposes to reduce cost. Is there anything that is easily reversible, whether an independent library or something I can utilize myself to reduce storage costs. It's totally okay if this hash function is reversible publicly and isn't meant for privacy at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, a hash function isn't reversible. If you want it to be reversible you have to use something else.

If I understood correctly, you want to compress data. So you could either use some sort of compression, or in the case of an array of `uint`s, maybe even some sort of packing (for example https://fravoll.github.io/solidity-patterns/tight_variable_packing.html). Or if you know the actual values are small, you could even manually pack multiple `uint`s into a single `uint` in some fashion.